# Convert string[] of json object to List<T>

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I am using json.net for json object parsing.
I have a string array that has of Json objects. so instead of 1 string with Json Array, I have each json object on different index of string array.

I need to de-serialize this string[] of json object into `List<T>`.

If it was string of Json Array to `List<T>` I would call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(result);`

But for this what would be the best approach to convert `string[]` of jsonobject into `List<T>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in a very simple way using Linq :

```
var list = jsonobjects.Select(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably just have to call `DeserializeObject` on each string in the array.

```
var list = new List<T>();
foreach (var jsonString in result)
    list.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
```